# Using import and export with TypeScript and depending on RequireJS

Tags: typescript, requirejs

I'm attempting to convert a large JavaScript application from Backbone/Marionette to TypeScript.

As I'm converting things, I would like to take advantage of exporting and importing classes using files as modules.

Am I correct that to do this, I need something like RequireJS?  I was hoping to focus on just the TypeScript part first before converting my app to work with RequireJS(which seems like a larger effort than the TypeScript conversion).

So... Is there a way to use file modules in TypeScript without also making the app work with RequireJS?

thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I correct that to do this, I need something like RequireJS? I was hoping to focus on just the TypeScript part first before converting my app to work with RequireJS(which seems like a larger effort than the TypeScript conversion).

You need some *module loader* as browsers don't have native support for that. However you don't need to use `requirejs` in fact I highly recommend moving to `commonjs` (it will help with code reuse on NodeJs / NPM etc). For `bundling` I recommend webpack : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Will commonjs make it easier to convert my app than if I used RequireJS?  I'm imagining that I'll need to do a lot to make my app work with a module loader first.

Comment: `I'm imagining that I'll need to do a lot to make my app work with a module loader first.` Yes. But in the absence of the one an app probably doesn't do what one expects it to do : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md Or becomes an unanalyzable mess

Comment: `Will commonjs make it easier to convert my app than if I used RequireJS` Yes. You get `npm` for free. Its where the JavaScript is now https://twitter.com/basarat/status/671930970690347009